# Create split archives (zip, rar, 7z)?

Tags: python, split, zip, 7zip, rar

**In short:**

- I **need** to split a single (or more) file(s) into multiple max-sized archives using dummy-safe format (e.g. zip or rar anything that work will do!).
- I **would love** to know when a certain part is done (callback?) so I could start shipping it away.
- I would **rather not** do it using rar or zip command line utilities unless impossible otherwise.
- I'm trying to make it os independent for the future but right now I can live if the compression could be made only on linux (my main pc) I still need to make it easily opened in windows (wife's pc)

**In long:**

I'm writing an hopefully to-be-awesome backup utility that scans my pictures folder, zips each folder and uploads them to whatever uploading class is registered (be it mail-sending, ftp-uploading, http-uploading).

I used zipfile to create a gigantic archive for each folder but since my uploading speed is really bad I let it work at only at nights but my internet goes off occassionally and the whole thing messes up. So I decided to split it into ~10MB pieces. I found no way of doing it with zipfile so I just added files to the zip until it reached > 10MB.

Problem is there are often 200-300MB and sometimes more videos in there and again we reach the middle-of-the-night cutoffs.

I am using Subprocess with "rar" right now to create the split archives but since directories are so big and I'm using large compression this thing takes ages even the first files are already ready - this is why I love to know when a file is ready to be sent.

So short story long I need a good way to split it into max-sized archives.
I am looking at making it somewhat generic and as dummy-proof as possible as eventually I'm planning on making it some awesome extensible backup library..

Comment: "my internet goes off occassionally and the whole thing messes up" That's what rsync is for.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams yup I'm familiar with rsync (and csync for ftp) but I want to backup using either mail or http-uploading so I could fetch it anywhere or at let my parents fetch it anywhere and enjoy videos of their grand-daughter making tons of mess ;)

Comment: Use the split command: http://www.computerhope.com/unix/usplit.htm

Comment: @ben.pere http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Python-Mark-Lutz/dp/0596009259 has the solution and a few other things. I don't have the book anymore and forget the details, but I do know it's here.

Comment: you could leverage a torrent library: 1. there are implementations in Python 2. it supports big files, big number of files; it can work with unreliable internet connection. 3. you could deliver new content using rss with links to new torrent files. Or there is probably already a dropbox-like clone implemented on top of torrents.